# Apple Developer Certificate: Incorrect Team ID

Tags: ios, certificate

A recent attempt to build an app failed and I realized that the App ID prefix (Team ID) was different from the Team ID of my developer certificate.  The prefix of my Distribution certificate is correct and matches my Team ID.  My account is an individual one and I have attempted several times revoking and reissuing my Development certificate, but each time it is generated, it produces a certificate with a different Team ID.

To recap:
App Identifier Prefix (on iTunes Connect): 8RJ7xxxx
Distro Certificate Team ID: 8RJ7xxxx
Development Certificate Prefix: 5PM6xxxx

Result: Develpoer team ID mismatches (between XCode and Certificates in Keychain) prevent app from being code signed.

Has anyone seen/corrected this issue?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a back and forth with iOS Developer Help personnel, we've determined that:
The Team ID for the Development Certificate is randomly assigned and will be different from the Distribution Certificate.  The arbitrary Team ID for the Development Certificate ultimately has no bearing on reality.  The code signing issues I was having were coincidental and were eventually fixed by (what you can read elsewhere on this site) revoking everything, re-issuing all certificates...and (what I was not doing) WAITING PATIENTLY (took about a day) before everything went back into effect.

Comment: Thanks!! This ***WAITING PATIENTLY*** did the trick - in my case, even didn't have to revoke *everything*!

Answer (score 0):

if you login into https://developer.apple.com you will see in the "Identifiers" part, that every of your prefixes is an other one.

Check if your developer provisioning profile (I think it's the Wildcard profile) is connected correct with your certificate. Or you can delete it an synch again with xcode so it will create a new one by itself :)

Comment: Thanks geo.  That is exactly the issue - the provisioning profile ID (along with all other profiles) is 8RJ7xxxx.  The issue is that my Developer Certififacte is ID 5PM6xxx, no matter how many times I revoke it and create a new one.
I've also deleted/recreated the XCode managed iOS Team Provsioning Profile you mentioned, whose ID is the current and correct 8RJ7xxx.

Comment: short question: where do you try to codesign it? while building or while resign? if want to make an .ipa or to upload it to store with a wildcard profile, you will fail

Comment: Yeah, not using any wildcards...using Development Provisioning Profiles I created for the App.  The codesigning occurs when I am attempting to run the app on my device, not yet attempting to archive yet.

Answer (score 0):

I found the similar issue.
I had different ID’s both on generated certificate and provisioning profile.
When I restarted my machine Xcode was able to re-fetch the matching certificates.
This could be the Xcode bug to identify the exact certificate for the provisioning profile.

```
Restart you system and check Your Xcode settings
```

Answer (score 0):

None worked for me so my solution is

Go to `Signing & Capabilities` (that tab you enable auto signing)

Disable `app groups / entitlements`. That worked for me.